# How to change mysql root password

Tags: mysql, macos, passwords

I'm trying to change the mysql root password on my machine. Another engineer created the password and left the company so I don't have access. I'd rather not have to reinstall the whole shebang.

I'm trying to follow the instructions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

But when I execute the command on step 2 of the "Resetting the Root Password: Unix Systems" instructions I get the following error:

```
FitValet-MacBook-Pro:~ fitvalet$ kill `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/FitValet-MacBook-Pro.local.pid`
cat: /usr/local/mysql/data/FitValet-MacBook-Pro.local.pid: Permission denied
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

And I can't figure it out for the life of me...permission is denied? How can I get past this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `sudo` in front of the `kill` and `cat` commands. Like this:

```
sudo kill `sudo cat /usr/local/mysql/data/FitValet-MacBook-Pro.local.pid`
```

It will then ask you for the root password for your Mac (not mysql). Enter it, and the command should execute without giving you a permission denied error.

Comment: Amazing how four letters made all the difference.

Comment: @YPCrumble: Those 4 letters are a common idiom in *nix systems http://xkcd.com/149/